# PIL.Image from picamera.capture()

Tags: python, raspicam, image

I want to get an image from the pi camera module and use the pillow imaging library to modify the image. The way I have been doing it up to now is to take a picture with the camera and then open that file using:

```
from PIL import Image

Im = Image.open("the file path")
```

That has worked well, but I don't want to save the image until I have modified it.
    is there a way of doing:

```
Im = camera.capture() #where Im is a PIL image

print(Im.width) # or any other PIL.Image property / method
```

Thanks

Comment: For any particular reason?  If it's to reduce SD card wear then save the file to a small RAM disc initially.

Comment: I thought it would be quicker. I have to take a lot of images and writing each one to disk ,and then reading it back into memory seems like a waste of time.

Comment: A RAM disk is just memory, and will minimise the overhead, plus it'll save wear and tear on the SD card.

Comment: There's a [recipe precisely for that in the docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-pil-image) (uses an in-memory stream and opens the result in PIL)

Answer (score 8):

From the [picamera docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-pil-image) (Section 4.3. Capturing to a PIL Image):

```
import io
import time
import picamera
from PIL import Image

# Create the in-memory stream
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
# "Rewind" the stream to the beginning so we can read its content
stream.seek(0)
image = Image.open(stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way i do it is with OpenCv, you can also modify images with OpenCv such as draw images,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def cv2_to_pil(img): #Since you want to be able to use Pillow (PIL)
    return Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

def pil_to_cv2(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Define the camera, 0 is which camera, if you have more than 1
ret_val, img = cam.read() #cam.read() returns ret (0/1 if the camera is working) and img, 
#the actual image of the camera in a numpy array

cv2.imshow("Camera", img) #if you wanted to open a window to see this picture
cv2.waitKey(0) #waits for the enter key to continue, change to
#0 to X milliseconds to stop for a certain amount of time.

pil_img = cv2_to_pil(img) #convert the image to PIL so you can use it that way.
```